# nginx reverse proxy server multiple websites file arrangements

Tags: nginx, hosting

I follow [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/develop-deploy-first-fullstack-web-app) article. I wonder what should be the file structure of "/etc/nginx/sites-available" if I want to host multiple websites and what should be the content of each files under "sites-available" folder (Look at the sample "default" file content down below for a single website configuration)?

I am running node.js, express.js and EJS for 2 websites.
I created 2 different instances of the same website like this:

```
/home/debian/public
/home/debian/public2
```

Under both of these folders, each of them has their own individual "server.js" file and the content of them are like this:

server.js

```
// Load Node modules
var express = require('express');
const ejs = require('ejs');
// Initialize Express
var app = express();
// Render static files
app.use(express.static('/home/debian/public'));
// Set the view engine to ejs
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
// Port website will run on
app.listen(8080);
// *** GET Routes - Display Pages ***
// Root Route
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    var listnames = ["1", "2", "3];
    // Render index page
    res.render('/home/debian/public/views/pages/index.ejs', {
        // EJS variable and server side variable
        listnames: listnames
    });
});
```

I configured one public folder's port to 8080 and public2 to 9000

According to [this article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/develop-deploy-first-fullstack-web-app) if you have only a single server, the file "default" under "/etc/nginx/sites-available" should be configured like this:

default

```
server {
        root /var/www/html;      
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name auroraspotter.space;
         
location / {
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
       proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
       proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
       proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
       proxy_redirect off;
 }
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/auroraspotter.space/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/auroraspotter.space/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
server {
    if ($host = auroraspotter.space) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
    
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        
        server_name auroraspotter.space;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
```

However, I wonder what should be the file structure of "/etc/nginx/sites-available" if I want to host multiple websites and what should be the content of each files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can have only 1 file named `default.conf` but you need to edit it as follows:

```
server {
        root /var/www/html;      
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name auroraspotter.space;
         
location /path1 {
       proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;

       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
       proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
       proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
       proxy_redirect off;
 }

location /path2 {
       proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;

       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
       proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
       proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
       proxy_redirect off;
 }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/auroraspotter.space/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/auroraspotter.space/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
server {
    if ($host = auroraspotter.space) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
    
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        
        server_name auroraspotter.space;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
```

Now when you will send request to `auroraspotter.space/path1`, it will be served by nodejs running on port 8080 and when you will send request to `auroraspotter.space/path2`, it will be served by nodejs running on port 9000.